# Why do MySql multiple queries cause syntax error, while separately work successfully?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to load data from a csv with the following code.

```
$loadsql = 'delete from tablecreate where table_name=\''.$tablename.'\';
LOAD DATA INFILE \'/wamp/www/mytools/tablecreate/tables/'.$tablename.'.csv\' 
INTO TABLE tablecreate 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\' 
LINES TERMINATED BY \'\\r\\n\' 
IGNORE 2 LINES;';

$result = mysqli_query($con, $loadsql);
if (!$result) { 
    echo "sorry!! data could not be loaded!".mysqli_error($con)."<br>" ;
    echo "your sql is following<br>".$loadsql;
}

else {
    echo "<br>"."data loaded successfully."."<br>" ;
     }
```

When I run this on phpmyadmin, the query works correctly. But when I run the above php code in the browser, the output is as follows:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LOAD DATA INFILE '/wamp/www/mytools/tablecreate/tables/subjects.csv' INTO TABL' at line 1

your sql is following

```
delete from tablecreate where table_name='subjects';
LOAD DATA INFILE '/wamp/www/mytools/tablecreate/tables/subjects.csv' 
INTO TABLE tablecreate FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 2 LINES;
```

> I added the above line just to debug it and to see the actual contents of `$loadsql`, Can't understand why a copy paste of the following sql in phpmyadmin works perfectly.

**UPDATE**

Tried  executing the two statements separately, by commenting out either of them. one at a time, both of them work fine, the problem is they don't work together.

**Just a thought**

in multiple queries if one is successful and the next fails, what would `$result` return then?

Comment: remove the semi-colon in the first line. it's an end of statement character

Comment: but as there are two statements in this sql, don't I need it?

Comment: that would generate a syntax error in phpmyadmin as well!

Comment: @Fred-ii-, Please help me. .....to save your time, would you like me to provide you with the table structure I'm working upon, and the csv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute multiple queries in a single call use [mysqli_multi_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php). Although it is not entirely clear from the documentation, but mysqli_query() can only execute a single query at a time.

Comment: +1 for correctness, with the caveat that enabling multi-query support opens up security holes big enough to drive a truck through, if there's even the remotest possibility of a SQL injection vulnerability in *your* code... I don't allow this anywhere, at all, ever, in any of my environments.  It's just a bad practice.  Run the queries sequentially.  Or in parallel on multiple connections.