# Why error occurs when I send multiple queries into mysqli_query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, adminer

The same request in the Adminer has no errors, but in php is

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SET @lastID = last_insert_id(); INSERT INTO
>   p_messages(letter_id, user_id, messa' at line 1).

PHP:

```
$DB->query("INSERT INTO p_letters(user_1_id, user_1_name, create_date) VALUES ('".htmlspecialchars($accountId)."', '".htmlspecialchars($username)."', now()); SET @lastID = LAST_INSERT_ID(); INSERT INTO p_messages(letter_id, user_id, message) VALUES (@lastID, '".htmlspecialchars($accountId)."', '".htmlspecialchars($text)."');");
```

SQL:

```
INSERT INTO p_letters(user_1_id, user_1_name, create_date) VALUES ('acc583bfa62de6f66.05116379', '212312313', now()); SET @lastID = LAST_INSERT_ID(); INSERT INTO p_messages(letter_id, user_id, message) VALUES (@lastID, 'acc583bfa62de6f66.05116379', 'Проверка');
```

Comment: Multiple SQL statements? Have one query per statement.

Comment: use multi_query() instead of query()

Comment: multi_query() works, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do MySql multiple queries cause syntax error, while separately work successfully?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36240283/why-do-mysql-multiple-queries-cause-syntax-error-while-separately-work-successf)

Answer (score 2):

You are supposed to run your queries with separate API calls.

```
$DB->query("INSERT INTO ...");
$DB->query("SET @lastID = LAST_INSERT_ID()");
$DB->query("INSERT INTO ...");
```

note that you don't actually need the second query here as LAST_INSERT_ID() can be used directly.

Besides, you should never use a function named "**HTML** speacial chars" for any database interaction. You have to use prepared statements instead.

Note that a suggestion to use multi_query is unjustified and misleading, causing a lot of problems.