# Error SQL create temp table with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I try to select multiple values from a table, playlist_generate, with a condition, create a temp table, update a field and than insert in my table

```
$data_tabella_duplicata = $_POST['data_duplicata'];
$data_iniziale_originale = $_GET['data_iniziale'];

$query_duplica_playlist = "
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_table;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table LIKE playlist_generate;
SELECT data_playlist, giorno_playlist, orario_playlist, nome_evento,nome_programma FROM playlist_generate WHERE data_playlist = '".$data_iniziale_originale."';
UPDATE temp_table SET data_playlist='".$data_tabella_duplicata."';
INSERT INTO playlist_generate SELECT null,data_playlist, giorno_playlist,orario_playlist, nome_evento, nome_programma FROM temp_table;
DROP TABLE temp_table;
";

$esegui_query_duplica_playlist = $connessione->query($query_duplica_playlist);
if ($connessione->error) {
try {
    throw new Exception("MySQL error $connessione->error <br> Query:<br> $query_duplica_playlist", $connessione->errno);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error No: ".$e->getCode()." - ".$e->getMessage()."<br >";
    echo nl2br($e->getTraceAsString());
}
}
```

but i have an error I don't understand

> Error No: 1064 - MySQL error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table LIKE playlist_generate; SELECT data_playlist, ' at line 2

I try the code in phpmyadmin and it works

if I use this

```
$query_duplica_playlist = "
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_table;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table ENGINE = MEMORY;
SELECT data_playlist, giorno_playlist, orario_playlist, nome_evento,nome_programma FROM playlist_generate WHERE data_playlist = '".$data_iniziale_originale."';
UPDATE temp_table SET data_playlist='".$data_tabella_duplicata."';
INSERT INTO playlist_generate SELECT null,data_playlist, giorno_playlist,orario_playlist, nome_evento, nome_programma FROM temp_table;
DROP TABLE temp_table;
";

$esegui_query_duplica_playlist = $connessione->multi_query($query_duplica_playlist);
```

I have no result

Comment: You can only run ONE query using `->query()` you are trying to run 6

Comment: Why are you coding a try/catch block inside a `If error` test. Why not just output the error mesage

Comment: @RiggsFolly so I have to use ->multi_query() ?

Comment: Thats possible but I would check out @JayBlanchard answer. I would personally do it in 6 seperate queries using `->query()` as processing the results of a multi_query can get a little painful IMHO

Comment: Why do you need that ?

Comment: I want to speed up the process with unique query, in my case I want duplicate some values and a different date, in this query I have more than 700 rows

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html) -

> **You cannot use CREATE TEMPORY TABLE ... LIKE to create an empty table based on the definition of a table that resides in the mysql tablespace**, InnoDB system tablespace (innodb_system), or a general tablespace. The tablespace definition for such a table includes a TABLESPACE attribute that defines the tablespace where the table resides, and the aforementioned tablespaces do not support temporary tables.

In addition, you appear to be trying to run multiple queries at once. If you're using MySQLi you will want to use [`multi_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php). Using `multi_query()`, especially in a situation such as this *is not ideal* so consider your logic carefully should you find yourself wanting to use this function.

Comment: Mornin' Jay. I did not know that :)

Comment: Mornin' @RiggsFolly. I found this out quite by accident one late and very frustrating night, much as I do all of my programming problems :)

Comment: Hi,
so I have to use CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table ENGINE = MEMORY;

Comment: Yes, to create a blank table.you could perform a `SELECT` like `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE new_tbl SELECT * FROM orig_tbl LIMIT 0;`

Comment: IMHO, it's a bad idea to recommend `multi_query()`. From what I can tell, it makes things more complicated for little benefit.

Comment: The create temporary table observation is useful, but irrelevant here (the OP wrote the queries worked in phpmyadmin). The multiple query issue has already been answered dozens of time here on SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard sorry, I don't understand

Comment: Why irrelevant @Shadow? Has the `LIKE` syntax been covered before? The error being generated for the OP is because of the syntax, not because of the multiple queries. I could not find a duplicate for that syntax issue.

Comment: I agree @Barmar, only mentioning it in order that the OP might continue to learn.

Comment: What do you not understand @user1712790

Comment: So the best way is make more single query?

Comment: Maybe if I create a real table and I use this table as a “temp table” and I separate the queries is a Bad solution?

Comment: You should separate the queries, no matter what. then test your temp table creation. If it works separately you'll be good to go. If it doesn't use a CREAT TABLE query as I have shown in comments.

Comment: If the error was related to the issue you describe, then 1) it would not be a syntax error 2) the code would not have run in phpmyadmin. If you use the query() method in mysqli to execute multiple sql statements, then you get a syntax error for the 2nd statement - just like here. So yes, the error in the question is caused by the multiple sql statements and you were wrong to remove the dupe hammer.

Comment: See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40844497/why-error-occurs-when-i-send-multiple-queries-into-mysqli-query

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all.
So the best way to do this is make more queries.
Thanks

```
// 1 query
$query_seleziona_data_controllo        = "SELECT data_generata FROM data_generata WHERE data_generata ='".$data_tabella_duplicata."' ";
$esegui_query_seleziona_data_controllo = $connessione->query($query_seleziona_data_controllo);

$numero_righe_query_controllo = $esegui_query_seleziona_data_controllo->num_rows;
if ($numero_righe_query_controllo == 0) {

// 2 query
$query_duplica_playlist = "INSERT INTO playlist_generate_temp
SELECT null,data_playlist, giorno_playlist, orario_playlist, nome_evento,nome_programma FROM playlist_generate
WHERE data_playlist = '".$data_iniziale_originale."' ";

$esegui_query_duplica_playlist = $connessione->query($query_duplica_playlist);

// 3 query
$query_update_data_nuova = "UPDATE playlist_generate_temp SET data_playlist='".$data_tabella_duplicata."' WHERE data_playlist = '".$data_iniziale_originale."' ";

$esegui_query_update_data_nuova = $connessione->query($query_update_data_nuova);

// 4 query
$query_inserisci_duplicato = "INSERT INTO playlist_generate
SELECT null,data_playlist, giorno_playlist, orario_playlist, nome_evento,nome_programma FROM playlist_generate_temp
WHERE data_playlist = '".$data_tabella_duplicata."' ";

$esegui_query_inserisci_duplicato = $connessione->query($query_inserisci_duplicato);

// 5 query
$query_truncate_temp = "TRUNCATE TABLE playlist_generate_temp";

$esegui_query_truncate_temp = $connessione->query($query_truncate_temp);

mysqli_close($connessione);

} else {

echo "";
}
```